# find + xargs: argument line too long

Tags: xargs, arguments

I have a line like the following:

```
find /foo/bar -name '*.mp4' -print0 | xargs -i {} -0 mv -t /some/path {}
```

but I got the following error:

```
xargs: argument line too long
```

I am confused. Isn't the use of `xargs` supposed to precisely help with this problem?

**Note:** I know that I can techincally use `-exec` in find, but I would like to understand why the above fails, since my understanding is that `xargs` is supposed to know how to split the input into a manageable size to the argument that it runs. Is this not true?

This is all with zsh.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well for one thing the `-i` switch is deprecated:

```
-i[replace-str]
     This  option  is a synonym for -Ireplace-str if replace-str is specified. 
     If the replace-str argument is missing, the effect is the same as -I{}. 
     This option is deprecated; use -I instead.
```

So when I changed your command around to this, it worked:

```
$ find /foo/bar -name '*.mp4' -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 mv -t /some/path {}
```

#### Example

```
$ find . -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 echo {}
.
./.sshmenu
./The GIT version control system.html
./.vim_SO
./.vim_SO/README.txt
./.vim_SO/.git
./.vim_SO/.git/objects
./.vim_SO/.git/objects/pack
./.vim_SO/.git/objects/pack/pack-42dbf7fe4a9b431a51da817ebf58cf69f5b7117b.idx
./.vim_SO/.git/objects/pack/pack-42dbf7fe4a9b431a51da817ebf58cf69f5b7117b.pack
./.vim_SO/.git/objects/info
./.vim_SO/.git/refs
./.vim_SO/.git/refs/tags
...
```

#### Use of `-I{}`

This approach shouldn't be used since running this command construct:

```
$ find -print0 ... | xargs -I{} -0 ...
```

implicitly turns on these switches to `xargs`, `-x` and `-L 1`. The `-L 1` configures `xargs` so that it's calling the commands you want it to run the files through in a single fashion.

So this defeats the purpose of using `xargs` here since if you give it 1000 files it's going to run the `mv` command 1000 times.

#### So which approach should I use then?

You can do it using xargs like this:

```
$ find /foot/bar/ -name '*.mp4' -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t /some/path
```

Or just have find do it all:

```
$ find /foot/bar/ -name '*.mp4' -exec mv -t /some/path {} +
```

Comment: Thanks! When you said `"This approach shouldn't be used"` which approach should be used instead then? Would `"find /foot/bar/ -name '*.csv' -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t some_dir'"` be a better solution? If so, **how** does `xargs` know in this case where in the `mv` command to feed in the arguments it gets from the pipe? (does it always place them last?)

Comment: @user815423426 - Doing it with just the `find ... -exec ...` is a better way or if you want to use `xargs` the `find ... | xargs ... mv -t ...` is fine too. Yup it always puts them last. That's why that method needs the `-t`.

Answer (score 7):

The option `-i` takes an optional argument. Since you put a space after `-i`, there was no argument to the `-i` option and therefore the subsequent `-0` was not an option to `xargs` but the second of 6 operands `{} -0 mv -t /some/path {}`.

With only the option `-i`, xargs expected a newline-separated list of file names. Since there was probably no newline in the input, xargs received what looked like a huge file name (with embedded null bytes, but xargs didn't check that). This single string containing the whole output of `find` was longer than the maximum command line length, hence the error “command line too long”.

Your command would have worked with `-i{}` instead of `-i {}`. Alternatively, you could have used `-I {}`: `-I` is similar to `-i`, but takes a mandatory argument, so the next argument passed to the `xargs` is used as the argument of the `-I` option. Then the argument after that is `-0` which is interpreted as an option, and so on.

However, you shouldn't use `-I {}` at all. Using `-I` has three effects:

- `-I` turns off quote processing, which `-0` already does.
- `-I` changes the string to replace, but `{}` is the default value.
- `-I` causes the command to be executed separately for each input record, which is useless here since your command (`mv -t`) is specifically intended to cope with multiple files per invocation.

Either drop `-I` and `-i` altogether

```
find /foo/bar -name '*.mp4' -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t /some/path {}
```

or drop xargs and use `-exec`:

```
find /foo/bar -name '*.mp4' -exec mv -t /some/path {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a bash for loop:

```
for FILE in *.mp4 ; do rm $FILE ; done
```

or if you'd like to see what's going on:

```
for FILE in *.mp4 ; do echo Removing $FILE ; rm $FILE ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing this while using the [fish shell](https://fishshell.com/).
This relates to how fish expands the replacement string `{}`

If you are using fish you need to escape the replacement string `\{\}`

```
| xargs -I \{\} echo \{\}
```

or use a different replacement string

```
| xargs -I ! echo !
```