# turf-cli + xargs: argument line too long

Tags: xargs

I'm using [turf-cli](https://github.com/turf-junkyard/turf-cli) (it can be installed with `sudo npm install -g turf-cli`) for creating some geospatial data. `turf-cli` is a wrapper for the [turf.js library](https://turfjs.org/) just so we can use its functionalities from the command line. Let's say I have the following script:

```bsh
turf random points 1000 {} > geojsonFile.json
turf sample geojsonFile.json 2
```

In this sample, the first line generates a GeoJSON with 1000 random points and the second line selects two features of this file. So far everything is fine.

Well, I don't want to generate temporary files to store the data from the first line, nor store it in a variable just so I can use it in the second line. The workaround that I found was using `xargs` as the following:

```bsh
turf random points 1000 {} | jq -c '' | xargs -0 -I {} turf sample {} 2
```

This script works fine as well. Basically, it's doing:

1. Using `turf` to generate 1000 random points in a GeoJSON output.
2. Using `jq` to compress the GeoJSON output into a single line.
3. Using `xargs` with an argument in order to execute `turf` a second time (since `turf` doesn't accept `stdin` arguments).

In my sample so far, I've generated only 1000 random points with `turf`. That's why everything works. However, if I try to increase the number of random points to 10000 by executing:

```bsh
turf random points 10000 {} | jq -c '' | xargs -0 -I {} turf sample {} 2
```

It returns me the error:

```
xargs: argument line too long
```

I've seen similar issues with `xargs` like [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83803/444310) where the solution is to use `| xargs -I {} -0 ...`... But I'm already using these parameters and it doesn't work in my case. Is there any way of making it work with `xargs` just so I can execute `turf` in it even when it's receiving a huge GeoJSON from the pipe?

Comment: If `turf sample <...> 2` expects a filename as an argument, does it really work with stuffing JSON in there directly? Also, have you tried process substitution? `turf sample <(turf random points 1000 {}) 2`

Comment: @muru Cool, I didn't know this process substitution syntax. It works! Actually, I don't know why but it really works sending the JSON as I showed on my samples. I did some more tests here and it works with `turf sample "$(cat file.json | jq -c '')" 2` as well (considering I have created `file.json` before executing it). But it has the same limit apparently, with 10000 lines it works and with 100000 lines it doesn't and returns me the error `bash: /usr/local/bin/turf: Argument list too long`. My assumption now is that it's more an issue with `turf` than with `xargs`...